# How would I edit a sprite on an SNES rom?

Tags: sprites, modding

I want to take the game Shaq Fu and change one of the sprites for my own. How would I go about doing it?

Comment: The google keyword you are looking for is "rom hacking"

Answer (score 6):

In general, you'd want to find a tool that can extract the sprite data and patch it back in to a ROM. You are more likely to find them for more popular games (such as [Final Fantasy 6](http://www.ff6hacking.com/forums/showthread.php?tid=477&pid=2709#pid2709)). Shaq Fu is, unfortunately for you, apparently not popular enough to warrant such things.

Your next step would be to look for a generic SNES sprite extractor or editing tool. The SNES used a specific [tile graphics format](http://emu-docs.org/Super%20NES/General/snesdoc.html#GraphicsFormat) for drawing sprite tiles, and many games would have simply stored their graphics directly in that required format in the ROM for simplicity. These generic tools can sometimes find and edit those. Search for "SNES sprite editor" or whatnot and you may find [some](http://www.romhacking.net/reviews/1229/) [examples](http://www.zophar.net/utilities/snesgraph.html).

If that doesn't work, because your game is one of the ones that opted for some unusual storage format or compression, you'll have to do things the hard way. The sprite data is still in the ROM somewhere, and will probably still be rendered normally once decoded. You can still dig through the game's [assembly](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Super_NES_Programming/Introduction_to_assembly) and find *where* the rendering is being set up (look for preparation of the appropriate OAM registers, et cetera) and hopefully work backwards from there.