# How can I extract sprites from a SNES games?

Tags: 2d

Planning to use some sprites for a fan project but the sprites I want haven't been ripped yet; how can I extract them in a usable form?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about _developing_ a game.

Comment: Where should it go?

Comment: I see. I had no intention of doing anything illegal with the final product (I wanted to construct a few gifs) but if asking threatens the community, go ahead and close the question.

Comment: @congusbongus It's probably not _illegal_, you're right. However I still don't think it's a valid topic here.

Comment: Try this http://renderhjs.net/shoebox/

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic, per se. I think [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111187/how-would-i-edit-a-sprite-on-an-snes-rom) is highly relevant; I was going to close as a duplicate but it occurs to me that what you want to *do* with the sprites is important. Do you plan to take these sprites, modify them and put them back in the game? If so, this is a duplicate. Or do you plan to take them, modify them but do something *other than* put them back in the hacked ROM? If so I think it's not a duplicate because answers like Balint's are valid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably with an emulator, the pront screeb button, and an eraser tool.

You could also open the game files with an editor, and copy them.